# Stack a dataframe on itself multiple times in R?

Tags: r

I would like to stack a dataframe 100 times on itself, with an additional column indicating the iteration number, similar to what `dplyr::bind_rows(..., .id = "id")` does. Or is there a way I can save 100 times my dataframe into a single list and then use `data.table::rbindlist()`?

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(iris, iris, .id = "id") #This stacks the data only twice
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(iris, iris), idcol = "id")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `replicate` to return the datasets in a `list` and then use `bind_rows` or `rbindlist`

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 5
replicate(n, iris, simplify = FALSE) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'id')
```

---

Or another option is `purrr::rerun`

```
library(purrr)
n %>%
   rerun(iris) %>% 
   bind_rows(.id = 'id')
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option with `rbind` + `lapply` + `cbind`

```
> n <- 100

> do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(n), function(k) cbind(id = k, iris)))
```

Comment: Thanks, great to have a base R option, could you please define n above (e.g. n = 100) for reproducibility.

Comment: @CyG yes, see my update